# htaccess redirect everything to 410

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to force all requested urls from a domain to a custom 410 error page. I am using the following rule, but it does not catch everything. I need it to catch all folders, .html, .php and jpgs etc...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^index\.html$ index.html [L,R=410]

ErrorDocument 410 /error-410.php
```

Can anyone help? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your root .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-410.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=410]
```

Comment: Thanks. It is actually a sub-domain that I am working on so I changed the rewritecond appropriately.This hatccess give a 410 response but does not show the custom 410 page. It generates a 500 server error instead.

Comment: Oh yes that is because even `/error-410.php` will cause same `410`. Try my updated rule now.